# Can a patent be granted without "reduction to practice"?

Tags: us20140356867

In reference to the patent: [US20140356867](https://www.google.com/patents/US20140356867)

Hello, I recently came across (US20170107560) NUCLEIC ACID ENRICHMENT USING CAS9, which does not have any data to suggest that the inventors have reduced the invention to practice. Is it likely that this patent will be granted?

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment on the likelihood of this particular patent application to get granted as I don't know the prior art. However it is true that you don't have to prove a patent works with data (at least in the US).